# HTML Paragraph parallel with Image

Tags: html, image, parallel-processing, paragraph

I am new to stackoverflow. I'm asking about HTML code. On my sourcecode, I have an image that's 214px height(and 163px width). I Have a figcaption with that also. If I Set a paragraph tag with that it won't appear next to it, but under it. I'm trying to avoid a CSS "position: absolute" answer because i want this to be mobile compatible as well. Just wondering if we can make it so a p tag appears to the same height but to a set weight parallel to the image. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Personal Webpage | Home</TITLE>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="content, homepage">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge, chrome=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon"
href="favicon.ico"
type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max width: 5120px)"/>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="center">
<header><img src="header.png" alt="alttext" height="44px" width="792px" border="1px"/></header><br><h3><b>lorem ipsum dolor solem amit</b></h3></div><br><img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="" height="214px" width="163px" border="1px"><figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
<p style="border: 1px solid black;" width="100px" height="214px">lorem</p></p>
</BODY>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this with the information provided but here are some ideas to try.

You can float the p next to the img or set it to display mode inline-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute css property. Paragraph re sizes it self with smaller screen

```
p{
  position:absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't seem to move in relation to my image. I have a line of words and another image before this one, so that poses a problem. Unless there's a workaround that scales it down as well.

Comment: edit your question and provide full code so we can edit it